# Android find Text Group and Highlight in ListView

Tags: android, regex, listview, highlighting

I am performing a search over Strings in an ArrayList. If the Term is found I need to highlight that term and return the a string with the word where the term is present plus a word before and after that word!

---

Example:
Term =  “some”
Searched String =  “This is my awesome test  String!”
Result = “my awesome test” (“some” should be highlighted here)

---

First off I am useless with RegEx and wouldn’t know where to start and secondly I’m not sure how to highlight text in a ListView, there are 3 TextViews per Row and I pass an Array with Data objects to the Adapter. Can I just give the Data Object Spanndable’s for highlighting?!

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error and some help i got this which seems to do the trick

```
(^|\S*\s)\S*term\S*($|\s\S*)
```